# Should I have two threads for input/output or use NIO?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, io, nio

I have been working on a (relatively) simple tcp client/server chat program for my networking class. The problem that I am running into is I am using blocking calls, such as `read()` and `writeBytes()`. So, whenever I try to send a message to my server, the server does not print it out until it writes one back. For this situation, would using one thread for input and one thread for output be the most sensible solution, or would using NIO serve me better? Just to give you an idea of what my code looks like now, my server is:

```
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    DataOutputStream output;
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
    String sentence;

    while ((sentence = inFromUser.readLine()) != null) {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            output = new DataOutputStream( connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes(sentence + "\n");

            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( 
                connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Client said: " + inFromServer.readLine());
            connectionSocket.close();
    }
```

The client code is essentially the same. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two threads unless you want to learn about NIO. The Java tutorial has examples of spawning threads to handle client connections to a ServerSocket. Look toward the bottom of ["Writing the Server Side of a Socket"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I go with the two threads, the calls will still be blocking but the threads will simulate non-blocking calls, right (which sounds like it would work)? I'm not quite sure that the tutorial you linked is what I need. There should only be one client and one server, but the client can send multiple messages to the server at a time without having to wait for a reply.

Comment: Those calls always block, yes. By using one thread for inbound traffic and one for outbound, they don't have to wait on each other because the whole point of threads is that they run at the same time, or at least pretend to, so one thread can be blocked waiting for input/output, and the other carries on doing whatever it needs to. You're right about the tutorial. It's not as close to what you're doing as what I was thinking it was. If you look at the "multi server", though, and imagine that the server holds on to the output stream while creating a thread to handle the input...